# PopOver TableView, error at cell in Swift IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

i am using ViewController in my application. in ViewController i try to popOver tableview using textfield. but having error

this my code popUp :

```
   Func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) ->  Bool{      

    if (textField == paymentTextField){
        var paymentVC = MasterPaymentTableViewController()
        paymentVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        paymentVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500)

        let popOverPresentationVC = paymentVC.popoverPresentationController

        popOverPresentationVC?.delegate = self
        popOverPresentationVC?.permittedArrowDirections = .Down

        popOverPresentationVC?.sourceView = textField as UIView

       self.navigationController?.presentViewController(paymentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

       return false
    }
  }
```

this error at code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterPaymentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myList : Array<AnyObject> = []
var appDel : AppDelegate!
var context : NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   context = appDel.managedObjectContext

   let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PayMethod")

   myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
   tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

  return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return myList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellID : String = "Cell"
    // ERROR AT HERE : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as! UITableViewCell
    // -------------
    if let ip = indexPath {
    var myObject : NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as! NSManagedObject

    let title = myObject.valueForKeyPath("paymentName") as! String

    cell.textLabel!.text = title
}


return cell
}
```

But, if i open tableView directly not from popOver, its working normal

any solution?
thx

Comment: You really need to put more details if you expect people to help you, post your code, highlight where the error happened, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

and use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method instead of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath:indexPath)
```

Comment: its works, no error. thx, i just want ask, if popover, bar button cant be shown? just cell its show up?

Comment: bar button can be shown on the `NavigationBar` inside an `UINavigationController`